# Verilator using wrong path for g++

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, centos, verilator

I am running a program called verilator.

I run the following command

```
verilator --build -Wall --trace -cc alu.sv
```

The above command needs a c++ compiler to work with. So the above command in turn tries to compile/generate c++ object files which makes it call the g++ compiler.

I get the following error

```
/homes/tinebp/tools/gnu/bin/g++-10  -I.  -MMD -I/home/verilator/include -I/home/verilator/include/vltstd -DVM_COVERAGE=0 -DVM_SC=0 -DVM_TRACE=1 -DVM_TRACE_FST=0 -DVM_TRACE_VCD=1 -faligned-new -fcf-protection=none -Wno-bool-operation -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-shadow      -std=gnu++14 -Os -c -o Valu__ALL.o Valu__ALL.cpp
make: /homes/tinebp/tools/gnu/bin/g++-10: Command not found
make: *** [Valu__ALL.o] Error 127
```

The path `/homes/tinebp/tools/gnu/bin/g++-10` does NOT exist. I do not understand why it is using that path??

I do not have a Makefile so the *make* cmd is using implicit rules. Idk where is it taking the compiler path from. Below are compiler paths

I manually checked and set the paths but I still the error. Here are c++ compiler paths.

```
$ echo $CXX
/package/gcc/11.2.0/bin/g++
$ which gcc
/package/gcc/11.2.0/bin/gcc
$ which g++
/package/gcc/11.2.0/bin/g++
$ echo $CC
g++
```

Comment: How did you install and configure Verilator?

Comment: It's opensource, you could try debugging it. Also try `printenv | grep /homes/tinebp/tools/gnu`.

Answer (score 1):

These paths are copied from the settings present [at compile time](https://github.com/verilator/verilator/blob/cfb73923bd6b7136240d3b3f4aed52c9724e0f4f/include/verilated.mk.in#L15-L20):

```
AR = @AR@
CXX = @CXX@
LINK = @CXX@
OBJCACHE ?= @OBJCACHE@
PERL = @PERL@
PYTHON3 = @PYTHON3@
```

You will need to edit the installed `include/verilated.mk` file and revert the hard-coded paths to generic ones (eg `CXX=g++` so you can use PATH-based lookups) OR change them to use `?=` instead, which allows overriding them from environment variables.

EDIT: You should contact whoever compiled this program for you and tell them to compile without setting `CXX` and other environment variables.